# Array not getting printed in html template LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template for:each={outerArray} for:item="arrayitem">
    <template for:each={arrayitem} for:item="item1">
                        <lightning-input
                            key={item1.value}
                            label={item1.label}
                            value={item1.value}
                            type="checkbox"
                        ></lightning-input>
     </template>
</template>
```

What is wrong in this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template for:each={arrayitem} for:item="item1">
```

This line needs a key so that the outer template knows which inner template is which. You can never *not* have a key value. You may need to restructure your data to match. Also, using "value" as the key is probably a bad idea, as it appears to be a Boolean value. Use an actual key, or something else that will be unique.

Here's a [sample](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/STtBznpwmyxnXzq8D7wr):

```
<template>
    <template for:each={outer} for:item="section">
        <template key={section.key} for:each={section.items} for:item="field">
            <lightning-input key={field.label} label={field.label} type="checkbox" checked={field.value}>
            </lightning-input>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  outer = [
    {
      key: 1,
      items: [
        { label: "Field 1", value: true },
        { label: "Field 2", value: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      items: [
        { label: "Field 3", value: true },
        { label: "Field 4", value: false },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```